# Переводчик в оффлайн режиме

Tags: android, перевод, поиск-api

Как можно подключить переводчик, чтобы он работал оффлайн? Я знаю, что можно использовать Google translate API или Яндекс.Переводчик API, но они требуют подключение к интернету. Другими словами, как можно скачать Гугл переводчик на свое приложение?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/support/translate-mobile-app/offline-mobile.html

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov, спасибо за ответ! Но проблема в том что пакет скачивает на приложение яндекс переводчик. А мне нужно чтобы он скачивался на мое собственное проиложение

Answer (score 1):

Яндекс и Гугл переводчики не живут в виде отдельных библиотек. Есть другие, например [вот](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JOSHUA/).
Качество перевода оценивать не решусь, но почти наверняка лучше, чем что-то изобретать самому